# Pick random array element, remove it, display a message when no more elements available

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Okay, so I'm making a website that generates a random self-harm alternative when the user presses a button. I am using the JQuery .load() method to display a array element, however I can't seem to find a way of removing the element from the array after it's been selected. I also want to display a message to inform the user once there are no more alternatives to show.

I have tried the .splice() and .shift() methods, but it still seems to be showing repeats. I'm probably just not using these correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
var skillList = new Array;
skillList[0] = "Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListAnxious.length)";
skillList[1] = "Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListAngry.length)";
skillList[3] = "Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListSad.length)";
skillList[3] = "Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListDistract.length)";
skillList[4] = "Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListThink.length)";
skillList[5] = "Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListSensation.length)";
skillList[6] = "Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListIllusion.length)";
skillList[7] = "Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListBizzare.length)";

var skillListAnxious = new Array;

var skillListSad = new Array;

var skillListAngry = new Array;
skillListAngry[0] = "skills.html #goForRun";
skillListAngry[1] = "skills.html #pillowFightWall";
skillListAngry[2] = "skills.html #breakSticks";
skillListAngry[3] = "skills.html #popBalloon";
skillListAngry[4] = "skills.html #calmJar";
skillListAngry[5] = "skills.html #scribbleonPeople";
skillListAngry[6] = "skills.html #stabFruit";
skillListAngry[7] = "skills.html #appleAgainstWall";
skillListAngry[8] = "skills.html #screamLoudly";
skillListAngry[9] = "skills.html #tearPaperObjects";
skillListAngry[10] = "skills.html #gym";
skillListAngry[11] = "skills.html #singtomusic";
skillListAngry[12] = "skills.html #pictureofangryness";
skillListAngry[13] = "skills.html #beatUpaStuffedBear";
skillListAngry[14] = "skills.html #bubblewrap";
skillListAngry[15] = "skills.html #popMultipleBalloons";
skillListAngry[16] = "skills.html #paperFillCrosshatches";
skillListAngry[17] = "skills.html #goForRun";
skillListAngry[18] = "skills.html #colourWholePaper";
skillListAngry[19] = "skills.html #throwIce";
skillListAngry[20] = "skills.html #cutSomethingElse";
skillListAngry[20] = "skills.html #cutSomethingElse";
skillListAngry[21] = "skills.html #writeDownandRip";
skillListAngry[22] = "skills.html #flattenCans";
skillListAngry[23] = "skills.html #heavyShoes";
skillListAngry[24] = "skills.html #tennis";
skillListAngry[25] = "skills.html #cutFruit";
skillListAngry[26] = "skills.html #markPicture";
skillListAngry[27] = "skills.html #slashBottle";
skillListAngry[28] = "skills.html #destroyPillows";
skillListAngry[29] = "skills.html #splatterPaint";
skillListAngry[30] = "skills.html #brushTeddyVicious";
skillListAngry[31] = "skills.html #watchFilm";

var skillListDistract = new Array;
skillListDistract[0] = "skills.html #cupTea";
skillListDistract[1] = "skills.html #hotBath";
skillListDistract[2] = "skills.html #mopBlood";

var skillListThink = new Array;
skillListThink[0] = "skills.html #butterflyProject";
skillListThink[1] = "skills.html #sample"

var skillListSensation = new Array;

var skillListIllusion = new Array;

var skillListBizzare = new Array;

function pick() {
  var skillChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * skillList.length);
  $(".resultContent").load(skillList[skillChoice]);
 if (document.filter.anxious.checked == true) {
  var skillChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListAnxious.length);
  $(".resultContent").load(skillListAnxious[skillChoice]);
 }
 if (document.filter.sad.checked == true) {
  var skillChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListSad.length);
  $(".resultContent").load(skillListSad[skillChoice]);
 }
 if (document.filter.angry.checked == true) { 
  var skillChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListAngry.length);
  $(".resultContent").load(skillListAngry[skillChoice]);
 }
 if (document.filter.distract.checked == true) { 
  var skillChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListDistract.length);
  $(".resultContent").load(skillListDistract[skillChoice]);
 } 
 if (document.filter.think.checked == true) { 
  var skillChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListThink.length);
  $(".resultContent").load(skillListThink[skillChoice]);
 }
 if (document.filter.sensation.checked == true) { 
  var skillChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListSensation.length);
  $(".resultContent").load(skillListSensation[skillChoice]);
 }
 if (document.filter.bizzare.checked == true) { 
  var skillChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListBizzare.length);
  $(".resultContent").load(skillListBizzare[skillChoice]);
 }
 if (document.filter.illusion.checked == true) { 
  var skillChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListIllusion.length);
  $(".resultContent").load(skillListIllusion[skillChoice]);
 }

}
```

Comment: please add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript's [.splice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method is what you need. Just replace every your call that gets the element like this:

```
skillListBizzare[skillChoice]
```

to this:

```
skillListBizzare.splice(skillChoice, 1)
```

It will return the chosen element and immediately remove it from the source array.

And on the next line you can check if there are some elements left:

```
if (skillListBizzare.length === 0) {
    alert('Sorry! No skills left');
}
```

Comment: if (document.filter.angry.checked == true) { 
  var skillChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * skillListAngry.length);
  $(".resultContent").load(skillListAngry.splice(skillChoice), 1);
 }

Comment: If thats how you meant, nothing happens now? Sorry if I'm doing it wrong

Comment: @J.Bates almost. You've messed up a bracket. Instead of `skillListAngry.splice(skillChoice), 1);` make it `skillListAngry.splice(skillChoice, 1);`. Be careful

Comment: Wow. It's amazing how much one bracket makes a difference. Thanks!

Comment: @J.Bates You're welcome :) And do not forget to check if there any skills left. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Without having seen your code*, I know that splice is probably the method you're looking for, but I'd really have to see how it's setup to advise on how to configure your code.

Comment: I've just uploaded it

Answer (score 0):

```
//remove the 20th index of skillListAngry array.
skillListAngry.splice(20,1);

if(skillListAngry.length === 0){
alert('there are no more items to display');
}
```

Comment: The lines for removing the element, wasn't so sure where to put them but thanks for the help with the message:)

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

// Function to generate random numbers
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}


// Loop through the array printing and splicing random index
while(array.length > 0) {
    var index = getRandomInt(0, array.length-1);
    console.log(array[index]);
    array.splice(index, 1); 
}
```

Here's a simple function to loop through an array randomly selecting and removing elements, hopefully this is of some help to you?